# how to filter all items in filter box with all check in superset

Tags: apache-superset

I know we can select all items separately in the filter box. But is there a way to have an item like all whereby clicking it we can choose all the items in the filter box?

Comment: Could you please provide more detail?

Comment: Please reformat (no caps in the question) and edit your answer to add more details.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also missing "All" option.